# Walker is not spawning nodes on the server

Tags: jaseci

I have this walker that’s spawn some nodes which works fine locally. On the server it’s running and reporting fine but the nodes are not there.

[[server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5zTi.png)]
[[locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGVnA.png)]

What I did

Jsserv makemigrations base
Jsserv migrate
Jsserv runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

login http://0.0.0.0:8000/

graph delete active:graph
jac build main.jac
graph create -set_active true
sentinel register -set_active true -mode ir main.jir

walker run init

Then i ran the walker that spawn the nodes

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is both jaseci_serve and jaseci versions the same?

Do pip show jaseci_serv and pip show jaseci

Most likely it's that

Comment: if not same make sure both are the latest

Comment: jaseci                            1.3.6.1
jaseci-ai-kit                 1.3.6.1
jaseci-serv                   1.3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete the makemigrations file and go over the process of migrating and making the migrations.

jsserv makemigrations
jsserv migrate

Comment: I deleted the jir and db file. Change port as well but same thing

Answer (score 0):

Have the walker print `here` and check that active graph in actions list is correct.

Comment: Also, can you share the implementations of the two walkers?

Comment: I edit the question with some picture